# Changing the default landing page in ASP.NET Core Razor page?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-2.2, asp.net-core-routing

I tried:

```
services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Index", "old");
    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/NewIndex", "");
}).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

This exception is thrown:

> AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints.
>   Matches:
>
> Page: /Index
>
> Page: /NewIndex

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51391725/6197785), that suggests renaming the Index page, but it obviously, if not a good reason presented, is a workaround. Can't I just change the default page without renaming the /Index page?

**EDIT**

The suggested SO threads don't cover the problem I explained, which is overriding the default route without having to rename the default `Index` page.
The accepted answer solved the problem.

Comment: Read the answer on following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49035516/avoiding-request-matched-multiple-actions-resulting-in-ambiguity-error-in-asp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change starting page, using Razor Pages in .NET Core 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46117717/how-to-change-starting-page-using-razor-pages-in-net-core-2)

Comment: Check out @sixto-saez's answer linked by Brad https://stackoverflow.com/a/55361078/5754
I checked it and it works

Comment: @adinas it does exactly what `AddRazorPagesOptions` do , just a shorthand version, and I'll need to change the name of the Index page

Comment: You don't need to change the name of the index page. Just give it a different page directive. So on the first line of the Index page put `@page "/old"` for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default pages in Razor Pages are those that have an empty string route template generated for them. You can use a custom `PageRouteModelConvention` to remove the empty string route template that gets generated for the *Index.cshtml* page, and add it instead to whichever page you want as your default page:

```
public class HomePageRouteModelConvention : IPageRouteModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(PageRouteModel model)
    {
        if(model.RelativePath == "/Pages/Index.cshtml")
        {
            var currentHomePage = model.Selectors.Single(s => s.AttributeRouteModel.Template == string.Empty);
            model.Selectors.Remove(currentHomePage);
        }

        if (model.RelativePath == "/Pages/NewIndex.cshtml")
        {
            model.Selectors.Add(new SelectorModel()
            {
                AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel
                {
                    Template = string.Empty
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

You register the convention in ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.Add(new HomePageRouteModelConvention());
}).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Latest);
```

You can read more about custom page route model conventions here: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/advanced/custom-route-conventions